# function create with show project details by id in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, controller

Controller:

```
    public function create(Request $id)
{
    $data = OperationalPlan::findOrFail($id);
    $val = explode("|-|",$data->text);
    $nval = explode("|-|",$data->ntext);
    $neval = explode("|-|",$data->netext);
    $newval = explode("|-|",$data->newtext);
    $mnue1 = StrategicGoal::get();
    $mnue2 = Measurement::get();
    $mnue3 = tawagh::get();
    $mnue4 = detailed_target::get();
    $mnue5 = Management::get();
    $mnue6 = Department::get();
    $mnue7 = activety::where([['department', Auth::user()->department],['is_confirmed', 1],['is_deleted',0],])->get();


    return view('user.report.create' . $id , compact('mnue1', 'mnue2','mnue3', 'mnue4', 'mnue5', 'mnue6','mnue7',
    'val', 'nval', 'neval', 'newval', 'data'));
}
```

route:

```
  Route::get('/report/create/{id}','User\ReportController@create')->name('dashboard.report.create.id');
```

url :

```
<a href="{{ route('report.create', $project->id) }}" class="" title="View">
```

the message error is :

```
Property [text] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

can some one helps me please i tried to fix this but i do not got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, remove the type-hint on `$id`. The 'id' being passed is NOT a `Request`:

```
public function create($id)
```

When you type-hinted that as `Request`, `$id` ends up being a `Request` object. When you pass that to `findOrFail` which will call `find` which will then call `findMany`, it will end up converting the `Request` to an array with `toArray()` since `Request` is `Arrayable`. This will end up returning a Collection because it thinks you are trying to find many records not a single record.

In short with what you had you ended up passing the array of inputs to `find`, not the 'id' you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you your answer helps me to find out the solution, I use find and also i use (Request $r) and defined a variable $id = $r->input('id'); .